# SELECT the teams with >1 spanish player

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, subquery

I am aware that this is a very easy question for the StackOverflow community. However I haven't found an answer to my problem on StackOverflow neither on other sites.

Let me explain the issue.

I want a query to select the teams with more than 1 Spanish player on them.

Those are the team (equipos) and player (jugadores) tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMC0J.jpg

My query:

```
SELECT
    nombre
FROM
    equipos
WHERE
    id IN (
        SELECT
            id_equipo
        FROM
            jugadores
        WHERE
            upper(procedencia) = 'SPAIN'
    )
GROUP BY nombre
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The query is not returning anything, however when I execute a test query to check if there are teams with more than 1 spanish player I get 1 team with 2 spanish players, so I would be expecting to get that team on my above query.

Test query returning a team with 2 spanish players:

```
SELECT
    j.nombre,
    e.nombre AS equipo
FROM
    jugadores j
JOIN equipos e ON j.id_equipo = e.id
WHERE
    upper(procedencia) = 'SPAIN';
```

Returning values:

```
Jorge Garbajosa Raptors
Jose Calderon   Raptors
Sergio Rodriguez    Trail Blazers
Pau Gasol   Lakers
Juan Carlos Navarro Grizzlies
```

As you can see the Raptors have 2 spanish players.
I must be missing something on my initial query. Im not sure about my HAVING CLAUSE tbh.

Comment: Do not include links in your question, instead include your sample data directly in your question as `formatted text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the query below with having clause

```
SELECT
    e.nombre AS equipo
FROM
    jugadores j
JOIN equipos e ON j.id_equipo = e.id
WHERE upper(procedencia) = 'SPAIN'
GROUP BY upper(procedencia), e.nombre
HAVING COUNT(j.nombre)>1;
```

Comment: Excellent. Just to clarify, why do you need a JOIN? Because the HAVING clause includes a condition from another table right?

Answer (score 2):

Your version would work if the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` were in the *subquery*:

```
SELECT e.nombre
FROM equipos e
WHERE e.id IN (SELECT j.id_equipo
               FROM jugadores j
               WHERE upper(procedencia) = 'SPAIN'
               GROUP BY j.id_equipo
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
              );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I haven't thought about this approach but it makes a lot of sense!